# ExtJs store datachanged event - How do we know which record got added\modified\updated

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs-stores

As per the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-event-datachanged), DataChanged event gets fired `whenever the records in the Store have changed in some way - this could include adding or removing records, or updating the data in existing records`

My question is how do we know which record(s) got added\deleted\modified. We only get store reference as the parameter.

Comment: You don't. `datachanged` is a catch-all event. Listen for specific events (`add`/`remove` etc).

Answer (score 2):

You don't know which change triggered the datachanged event, however, you can get changed records:

```
this.getModifiedRecords();
this.getRemovedRecords();
this.getNewRecords();
```